# Vague error when trying to add a foreign key to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I need to add a new foreign key to my table called `starList`. It currently does not have a foreign key relationship with the table called `planetList`.

So I ran this command:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[starList] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_starList_planetList] 
        FOREIGN KEY([planetId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[planetList] ([planetId])
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

But I get this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_starList_planetList".
> The conflict occurred in database "astro101", table "dbo.planetList", column 'planetID'.

I am not sure what that means.

I tried looking around my tables on SQL Server but I don't see anything wrong.

Could anyone help me figure out what the error means?

Thanks!

My `starList` table looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[starList]
(
    [starID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [galaxyID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [starTitle] [nvarchar](3000) NULL,
    [planetID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_StarList] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([starID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[starList] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_starList_galaxyList] 
        FOREIGN KEY([galaxyID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[galaxyList] ([galaxyID])
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[starList] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_starList_galaxyList]
GO
```

And the `planetList` table is this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[planetList]
(
    [planetID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [planetText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([planetID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: That error isn't particular vague, in my opinion. It's telling you that at least one existing row would cause the foreign key constraint to fail, thus it can't be created.

Comment: If you run `SELECT sl.planetId FROM dbo.starList sl LEFT JOIN dbo.planetlist pl ON sl.planetId = pl.planetId WHERE pl.planetId IS NULL;` you'll get the rows that will fail the `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: As a side note, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over a year, and you should be looking at upgrade paths ASAP.

Comment: @Larnu oh wow that makes sense!  I never knew that.  I ran that query and found a bunch of planetID values inside my starList table that don't exist inside the planetList table.  I will delete and re-run.  Do you think NULL values matter?  Because the planetId column in starList defaults to NULL.

Comment: `NULL` values are ignored for foreign key constraints, @SkyeBoniwell .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your data in both columns.

There is a value in the column of foreign key table whose associated value doesn't exist in the primary key table.

You have data in starlist.planetid which does not match/correspond to planetlist.planetid.

Both of them need to be the same with values values. It would be better to truncate them and then try creating the contraint.

In short, there is violation of referential integrity rules.

If this is the case, keep in mind to create foreign key before populating the tables.

Comment: Thank you let me look and see

Comment: You can simply update: update tbl set col=null; or drop and readd the column; alter table drop column x;
alter table add column x ;

Comment: Oh ok, so like: UPDATE starList SET planetID = NULL WHERE planetID NOT IN...

Comment: Truncate the entire column and then add constraint. So no where condition.